# Trend line in bubble chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart, trendline

I need to draw a trend line in a bubble chart in R. Is there any way to do so? I am struggling with `geom_smooth`and `geom_line`.

Here I copy a part of my data:

```
> dput(head(VAB2019ok[1:5,]))
structure(list(Branques = c("Alimentació", "Tèxtil", "Paper", 
"Químiques", "Farmàcia"), YEAR = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019
), VAB = c(6035, 2219, 2622, 4964, 3367), VABindu = c(14.3523032652382, 
5.27717662726819, 6.23558229684416, 11.8052747984494, 8.00732478774763
), VABcat = c(2.61293870093434, 0.960747469324489, 1.13523202549293, 
2.14923408640233, 1.45779032411697), Energia_TOTAL = c(10.0186261119859, 
11.9385601123305, 16.5214756745824, 33.5427238361767, 13.610937485108
), Var_IPI_2022 = c(2.05603357697997, 0.365172188766083, 2.58725653176655, 
1.41561322337203, 5.50581261504444), Branca_percVAB = c("Alimentació\n2,61 %", 
"Tèxtil\n0,96 %", "Paper\n1,14 %", "Químiques\n2,15 %", "Farmàcia\n1,46 %"
), vABcatdeci = c("6035", "2219", "2622", "4964", "3367"), VABcatdeci = c("2,61 %", 
"0,96 %", "1,14 %", "2,15 %", "1,46 %"), VABespai = c("6 035", 
"2 219", "2 622", "4 964", "3 367"), Branca_VAB = c("Alimentació\n6 035", 
"Tèxtil\n2 219", "Paper\n2 622", "Químiques\n4 964", "Farmàcia\n3 367"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

When I introduce the trend line, with `stat_smooth`, I get an error with `geom_text_repel`. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(VAB2019ok)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Energia_TOTAL, y=Var_IPI_2022, fill=VAB, size=VAB, text=Branca_VAB), alpha=0.5,shape=21, color="black")+
  stat_smooth(aes(x = Energia_TOTAL, y = Var_IPI_2022), method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 1), se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0, to=60, by=10))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0),color="grey60")+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    #axis.line.x=element_line(color="grey"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=15),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=12, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=0, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)))+
  geom_text_repel(data=VAB2019ok %>% filter (VAB>3000), aes(label=Branca_percVAB),  min.segment.length = Inf, vjust= 0.3, hjust=0.2, size=5)+   
  geom_text_repel(data=VAB2019ok %>% filter (VAB<3000), aes(label=Branques), min.segment.length = Inf, vjust=-0.1, hjust="inward", size=4)+
  scale_size(range=c(7,30))+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=F,guide="none",option="A", direction=-1)+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  labs(title="Pes de les branques industrials en el VAB català el 2019",
       y="Variació interanual IPI 2022 (%)",
       x="Dependència energètica 2011 (%)",
       caption="Font: Idescat. Marc Input-Ouput 2011")
```

Comment: Could you please share some data using `dput` and code you have tried?

Comment: how about `+ geom_smooth(method="lm")`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `geom_smooth(method="lm")` is not working.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(VAB2019ok)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stat_smooth` with a `poly` depending on what you want. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(VAB2019ok)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Energia_TOTAL, y=Var_IPI_2022, fill=VAB, size=VAB, text=Branca_VAB), alpha=0.5,shape=21, color="black")+
  stat_smooth(aes(x = Energia_TOTAL, y = Var_IPI_2022), method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 4), se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0, to=60, by=10))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0),color="grey60")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Using poly of 1 like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(VAB2019ok)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Energia_TOTAL, y=Var_IPI_2022, fill=VAB, size=VAB, text=Branca_VAB), alpha=0.5,shape=21, color="black")+
  stat_smooth(aes(x = Energia_TOTAL, y = Var_IPI_2022), method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 1), se = FALSE, color = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0, to=60, by=10))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0),color="grey60")
```

Output:

[image]

---

For your `geom_text_repel`, you should add the x and y variables like this:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(viridis)
ggplot(VAB2019ok)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Energia_TOTAL, y=Var_IPI_2022, fill=VAB, size=VAB, text=Branca_VAB), alpha=0.5,shape=21, color="black")+
  stat_smooth(aes(x = Energia_TOTAL, y = Var_IPI_2022), method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 1), se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0, to=60, by=10))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0),color="grey60")+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    #axis.line.x=element_line(color="grey"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=15),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=12, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=0, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)))+
  geom_text_repel(data=VAB2019ok %>% filter (VAB>3000), aes(x=Energia_TOTAL, y=Var_IPI_2022, label=Branca_percVAB),  min.segment.length = Inf, vjust= 0.3, hjust=0.2, size=5)+   
  geom_text_repel(data=VAB2019ok %>% filter (VAB<3000), aes(x=Energia_TOTAL, y=Var_IPI_2022, label=Branques), min.segment.length = Inf, vjust=-0.1, hjust="inward", size=4)+
  scale_size(range=c(7,30))+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=F,guide="none",option="A", direction=-1)+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  labs(title="Pes de les branques industrials en el VAB català el 2019",
       y="Variació interanual IPI 2022 (%)",
       x="Dependència energètica 2011 (%)",
       caption="Font: Idescat. Marc Input-Ouput 2011")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Maria, Please check my updated answer. As you can see when using a poly of 1 you can fit a Smooth line.

Comment: @Maria, Great to hear it worked! You could change the poly to whatever you want.

Comment: Yes thank you! But I got another error now. I am using `geom_text_repel` to label the bubbles, which was working before the trend line, but now I get: `Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y`. I copy my code

Comment: @Maria, see updated answer for your `geom_text_repel` call.